# Check if classes in modules implement the right interface

Tags: python, introspection, metaclass, abstract-methods

I have the following interface :

```
class Interface(object):

    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta


    @abc.abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        """Run the process."""
        return
```

I have a collections of modules that are all in the same directory. Each module contains a single class that implements my interface.

For example Launch.py :

```
class Launch(Interface):

    def run(self):
        pass
```

Let's say I have 20 modules, that implements 20 classes. I would like to be able to launch a module that would check if some of the classes do not implement the Interface.

I know I have to use :

- issubclass(Launch, ProcessInterface) to know if a certain class implements my process interface.
- introspection to get the class that is in my module.
- import modules at runtime

I am just not sure how to do that. 
I can manage to use issubclass inside a module.
But I cannot use issubclass if I am outside the module.

I need to  :

1. get the list of all modules in the directory
2. get the class in each module
3. do issubclass on each class

I would need a draf of a function that could do that.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
from os import listdir
from sys import path

modpath = "/path/to/modules"

for modname in listdir(modpath):
    if modname.endswith(".py"):

        # look only in the modpath directory when importing
        oldpath, path[:] = path[:], [modpath]

        try:
            module = __import__(modname[:-3])
        except ImportError:
            print "Couldn't import", modname
            continue
        finally:    # always restore the real path
            path[:] = oldpath

        for attr in dir(module):
            cls = getattr(module, attr)
            if isinstance(cls, type) and not issubclass(cls, ProcessInterface):
                # do whatever
```

Comment: I have tried but I get the message : Couldn't import myModule.py for each module of my folder.

Comment: Well, it worked for me. Although some debugging may still be necessary, I guess. You can try printing `path` each time it gets an error and make sure it only contains the directory that has your modules in it.